# Solutions of $ 0 = x^2 -ay^2 -1$ in $\mathbb F_q$ where $a$ is not a square.

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

Assume $F = \mathbb F_q$ where $q = p^r$ for $p$ prime and $r > 0$. I have to count
$$
 \{(x,y) \in F^2 \mid x^2 -ay^2 -1 = 0\}
$$ where $a$ is not a square in $F^*$. The equation is equivalent to $ay^2 = x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ so $y^2 = a^{-1} (x-1)(x+1)$ which means that $a^{-1}(x-1)(x+1)$ is a square. But $a$ is not so $a^{-1}$ is not thus $(x-1)(x+1)$ must be not a square. This means

- $(x-1)$ is a square and $(x+1)$ not or
- $(x+1)$ is a square and $(x-1)$ not

I use here several times the fact that $F^*$ a cyclic group is. Assume now that $(x-1)$ is a square. Is it then possible that $x+1$ is a square, too ? If this is not true I would get $(q-1)/2$ solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $F(\sqrt{a})$ is an extension of degree $2$ of $F$, and you have to count the number of its elements of norm $1$. This can be done using the famous Theorem

> **Hilbert 90**. If $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension whose Galois group is cyclic with generator $\sigma$, then $L^*/K^* \cong \ker(N_{L/K} : L^* \to K^*)$ via $[x] \mapsto \sigma(x)/x$

Comment: Why must I count the elements of norm 1 ?

Comment: Just compute the norm of $x+y \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2a} = 1 \iff x^2 +y^2a = 1 $. Then also $x^2 -y^2a = 1$?

Comment: No. Why do you think that? Do you know the definition of the field norm? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm